# Method in webservice returning false in release mode in Android Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with calling a webservice in release mode with Android Xamarin Forms. In debug mode everything works fine (also when I turn on the property 'Use shared Runtime' in release mode, but in this way I'm unable to create a apk package).

I can't get it working in release mode. I'm simple calling a webservice method. Everytime I call a method on the Webservice it returns false.

This is an example of my code:

```
public int ExecuteInsert(string tableName, Dictionary<string, object> valuesToSet)
{
    var client = new QuestionEngineClient();
    client.ExecuteInsertCompleted += delegate(object sender, ExecuteInsertCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        _result = args.Result;
        _resetEvent.Set();
    };

    client.ExecuteInsertAsync(tableName, valuesToSet, Constants.ConnectionString);
    var resetEventresult = _resetEvent.WaitOne(5000);

    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ShowToolTip", "ExceuteInsert: " + resetEventresult);

    return _result;
}
```

So resetEventresult is false in release mode (just returning 0 in the method 'ExecuteInsertAsync' on the webservice).

Comment: do you have Internet permissions enabled in the AndroidManifest?  This is done automatically in debug, but must be done explicitly for release.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, But I finally fixed it by turning on 'Use shared Runtime' and build the APK through a Powershell script.